# Command failed with exit code 1: git checkout refs/pull/3/merge

Tags: github, github-actions

Here is my `.github/workflows/ci.yml` (if you want to see the full project https://github.com/Lenny4/DeepFaceLabClient):

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  linux-ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2 # https://github.com/marketplace/actions/detect-and-tag-new-version#usage
      - uses: mikefarah/yq@master
      - uses: salsify/action-detect-and-tag-new-version@v2 # https://github.com/marketplace/actions/detect-and-tag-new-version#usage
        with:
          version-command: |
            yq '.version' pubspec.yaml
```

When I run it in github I got error `Error: Command failed with exit code 1: git checkout refs/pull/3/merge`

[image]

What am I missing here ?

In `pubspec.yaml` I got:

```yaml
# ...
version: 0.0.1+3
# ...
```

Comment: `uses: mikefarah/yq@master` is redundant as [`yq` is preinstalled](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md#tools) on `ubuntu-latest` runner.

Comment: Apparently, the problem seems to be your checkout step. Try with `fetch-depth: 0`.

Comment: @Azeem ok I will remove `uses: mikefarah/yq@master` but for `fetch-depth: 0` it's written in the documentation `since this action examines your git history to detect changes, you must set a fetch-depth of at least 2 with actions/checkout for that history to be present.`

Comment: Not sure about that 2 because the default is 1. See https://github.com/actions/checkout/tree/v2#usage. Did you test with `fetch-depth: 0`?

Comment: I just tried with `fetch-depth: 0` and I got error `Error: Command failed with exit code 1: git checkout refs/pull/3/merge`, I also tried with `fetch-depth: 1` and got error `Error: This appears to be a shallow clone of your project. To determine whether the project version has changed and a new tag needs to be created, you should set a \`fetch-depth\` of 2 or higher on \`@actions/checkout\`.`

Comment: I found that `fetch-depth: 2` reference from https://github.com/salsify/action-detect-and-tag-new-version.

Comment: I changed `on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]` to `on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]` and it works fine now

Comment: Good to hear that. There must be some reason for this. You might want to update your issue (https://github.com/salsify/action-detect-and-tag-new-version/issues/31) with the same and suggest its inclusion in the docs.

Comment: Also, consider using checkout v3 instead of v2.